# Test Class cannot get record type.

Tags: apex, unit-test

I am writing a test class to cover a method I have in a trigger handler. The logic is to see if the record type is "update" and a text field are populated.

Example:

```
public static List<Competitive_Intel__c> populateLookupFilter (List<Competitive_Intel__c> newList)
{
    List<Competitive_Intel__c> cisToInsert = new List<Competitive_Intel__c>();
    Map<ID,Schema.RecordTypeInfo> rt_Map = Competitive_Intel__c.sObjectType.getDescribe().getRecordTypeInfosById();

     for (Competitive_Intel__c ci : newList)
    {
        if(
            rt_map.get(ci.recordTypeID).getName().containsIgnoreCase('Update') &&
            ci.Competitive_Intelligence_Parent_Id__c != null
        )
        {
            cisToInsert.add(ci);
        }
    }
    return cisToInsert;
```

When I run my test I get the error:

> System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object

this is on the line:

```
rt_map.get(ci.recordTypeID).getName().containsIgnoreCase('Update') &&
```

My question is why am I getting the error if you are able to query for record types in test methods?

Test Method:

```
@isTest static void testLookupFilterSuccess()
{
    List<Competitive_Intel__c> ci = new List<Competitive_Intel__c>();
    List<RecordType> recordTypeUpdate = [SELECT Id 
                                         FROM   RecordType 
                                         WHERE  SobjectType = 'Competitive_Intel__c' 
                                         AND    DeveloperName = 'Update'];

    // insert a CI record and then use that for parent id. 
    Competitive_Intel__c c = new Competitive_Intel__c();
        c.Name = 'Dan Dan';
    insert c;

    Id tempId = getDummyId();

    ci.add(new Competitive_Intel__c(
        Id = tempId,
        RecordType = recordTypeUpdate,
        Competitive_Intelligence_Parent_Id__c = c.Id
    ));

    Test.startTest();
        List<Competitive_Intel__c> results = SL_Competitive_IntelTriggerHandler.populateLookupFilter(ci);
    Test.stopTest();

    System.assertEquals(ci, results,
        'Each record should be returned');
}
```

Comment: Contains might break in future versions of your code (say, someone adds a new record type "Update 2"). Consider `getName() == 'update'` instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As for the NPE, you need to check to ensure the map actually contains the value, especially in the case that the RecordTypeId of the record is null

```
if(rt_map.containsKey(ci.recordTypeID) &&
    rt_map.get(ci.recordTypeID).getName().containsIgnoreCase('Update') && ....
```

or (more optimized)

```
if(ci.recordTypeID != null &&
    rt_map.get(ci.recordTypeID).getName().containsIgnoreCase('Update') && ....
```

In this case there is no RecordTypeId so it may be causing the error if the insert causes the code to execute:

```
Competitive_Intel__c c = new Competitive_Intel__c();
        c.Name = 'Dan Dan';
    insert c;
```

Interesting to note (thanks sfdcfox)

```
RecordType = recordTypeUpdate
```

is assigning a list to an Object and is a legal construct, but only when you specify exactly one field. For example, you could have written

```
RecordType=new RecordType(Name='Update')
```

Otherwise you would have to do

```
ci.add(new Competitive_Intel__c(
        Id = tempId,
        RecordTypeId = recordTypeUpdate[0].Id,
        Competitive_Intelligence_Parent_Id__c = c.Id
    ));
```

Comment: Also, as an optimization: `if(ci.recordTypeID != null)` instead of checking if the map has a key.

Comment: @sfdcfox - yea, thought of that but did  not think it through. I guess if not null the way to code currently is the RT will always exist in the map. As long as code does not change it should be fine. Updated answer

Comment: Thanks for the help, would that mean it would be for( if( if( with two if statements in the loop or would you check if there is a record type before looping through each record?

Comment: @DanWooding - Apologies. Updated for your use case